# Нагрузка на скрипт

Tags: php

В коде часто приходиться пользоваться функциями:

```
echo;
```

и

```
print;
```

Какая из функций тяжелей и сильнее нагружает сервер?

Comment: на счет того что и как нельзя писать - почитайте про одинарные и двойные кавычки в php/ у меня ощущение что будет полезно

Comment: @IFreet хороший ответ на вопрос про print и echo :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Действительно, мы видим что print
> может оказаться немного медленнее echo
> (а может и не оказаться, что
> демонстрируют результаты по первым
> двум методам). В то же время
> использование echo с несколькими
> параметрами взамен конкатенации (и
> одинарными кавычками вместо двойных)
> даёт весьма ощутимый выигрыш в
> производительности.

Почитать [здесь можно](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/php/22951/) на эту тему.

Answer (score 1):

**echo** работает намного быстрее чем **print** т.к. echo не возвращает никаких данных, в отличии от print
О двойных и одинарных кавычках в PHP читаем [здесь](http://webproger.ru/Kavychki_v_PHP)
Выводы для себя каждый делает сам

Еще можно почитать [тут](http://tulvit.ru/post/162)

Comment: print тоже конструкция языка, если что

ЗЫ: почему так писать нельзя то ?

Ну то что выглядит не очень - это такое. Главная причина то какая ?

Comment: print работает как функция, echo просто тупо отдает<br>
По сабжу - гуглим и много много читаем о калькуляции строк в php и тестах производительности при использовании двойных и одинарных кавычек чтобы не задавть таких глупых вопросов -.-

Comment: > echo "привет $name"; //так писать нельзя :)

Поскольку такая запись проще записывается и легче читается, так писать можно и нужно. Во всяком случае программистам, которые оценивают свое время разработки значительно дороже процессорного времени.

Comment: Для меня легче читается вторая запись, причем намного...<br>
Сразу видно где статические данные а где переменные...<br>
<b>на вкус и цвет фломастеры разные</b>

Comment: > на вкус и цвет фломастеры разные

В таком случае не зачем было утверждать, что так писать нельзя.

Comment: обновил ответ...

Answer (score 1):

А лучше даже не так, как написал [[@AlexWindHope](/users/3545/alexwindhope)](/users/3545/alexwindhope)

```
echo 'привет ' . $name;
```

А так:

```
echo 'привет ' , $name;
```

Т.к. будет еще быстрее, это так же есть в статье, предложенной [[@Damon](/users/3072/damon)](/users/3072/damon)

Ну для "неверующих" провел тысты! Вывод 2-х переменных на экран через пробел. Количество операций вывода при одном прогоне - 10тыс., количество прогонов - 50, время среднее за все полмиллиона операций.
Скрин: [картинка внешняя ссылка](http://s1.ipicture.ru/uploads/20110925/t4clvP46.png)[image]

Comment: это все очень круто, но почему-то я ни в одном исходном коде не видел использования запятой в echo...<br>
более того - чаще используются двойные кавычки, а там где и не используются - используется точка...

Comment: AlexWindHope юзаю одинарную кавычку.

Comment: Я тоже, я не об этом, я о записи <br><b>echo 'привет ' , $name;</b><br> И о том что нигде ничкогде и никогла не видел такой записи, а поверьте мне, исходников я насмотрелся предостаточно :)

Comment: Вот
     
    echo 'привет' , $name;  

= 

    echo 'привет'; echo $name; 


я не думаю что это будет работать быстрей - что бы там не писали.

Comment: на 100% солидарен, это нелогично<br>

<small>более того - это должно работать <b>дольше</b></small>

Comment: Fatahan, важно не то, как вы думаете, а то, как работает php. Прирост скорости действительно ничтожный, но он есть и это доказано. И ваш пример с двумя echo будет работать так же быстрее, нежели пример через точку.

Comment: Почему-то когда я учил php было подругому О_о<br>
пошел гуглить, видимо "отстал от жизни"<br>
Кроме как надписи маленькими серыми буквами на хабре пока доказательств не нашел...<br>Пруфлинка нет так что это не аргумент, на php.net вообще ничего нету по этому вопросу...<br>По факту - нет пруфлинка(надпись гна хабре для меня доказательством не является) - нет причин этому верить...<br>
вообщем получается что запись<br>
`echo 'Hello ' . $name . ' you are '. $years . ' old';
надо выводить как:
echo 'Hello ',$name,' you are ',$years,' old'; //нигде такого не видел...`

Comment: @DemoS Обоснуйте. Почему через точку будет медленней?

Comment: Это горячка так выводить...

Comment: Обновил ответ, результаты теста перед вами!

Comment: О чем вы все спорите ? 

Очевидно, что при использовании точек в несколько приемов формируется строка, каждый раз на новом месте. Затем она передается в echo единственным аргументом. Запятые формируют список аргументов, по сути адресов строк, который передается в echo.

Ежу понятно, что быстрее.


А пишут с точками, а не запятыми, видимо из неких эстетических соображений и чтобы было похоже не на макросы какие-нибудь, а на серьезный язык. 

Короче, пальцы.

Comment: @Fatahan, а что тебе мешает повторить мой эксперимент?

Comment: @avp Я вот тоже не знаю о чём они спорят...такое ощущение как будто вопрос был про запятые и точки - а некоторые вообще не только коменты ещё и ответы начали оставлять на эту тему :)... @DemoS Вам не мешает ещё пару раз прочитать и понять смысл вопроса :)

Comment: Это всё экономия на спичках.

Answer (score 1):

Многократно выполнение
    $t0 = microtime(true);
    for($i=0; $i<10000; $i++){    echo "sdfsdfsdfsrn"; }
    echo microtime(true) - $t0;

и

```
$t0 = microtime(true);
for($i=0; $i<10000; $i++){    print "sdfsdfsdfs\r\n"; }
echo microtime(true) - $t0;
```

Не дало видимых выигрышей того или иного варианта.

**Личный вывод;** Быстродействие не в этом. Зачастую все уприраеться в работу с данными. Массивы файлы сокеты и тд

Comment: Быстродействие в этом, когда 90% кода заключается в двойные кавычки и так написано все. то поверьте мне, результаты вас бы "приятно" удивил бы

Comment: Строка умышлено заключена в двойные кавычки. 
Вам неверно не известно что значение \r\n и как они работаю в ' и "
Советую вам прочитал статью ссылка на которую приводилась выше http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/php/22951/

Comment: А при чем тут \r и \n к кавычкам?

Comment: При том что результат выполнения скрипта будет разный в зависимости от кавычек

Comment: вы думаете что я незнаю что такое \r\n? <br>
Вынужден вас огорчить, а вот вам бы погуглить и почитать о тестах производительности мягко говоря не помешало бы -.-<br>У вас все сразу же станет на свои места, уверяю

Comment: чёта Вы ваще.... :) - неужели вопрос настолько спорный и нет однозначного ответа?)

Comment: Я вам написал как надо - юзайте echo и одинарные кавычки... :P<br>

Comment: Александр Банов, вы абсолютно заблуждаетесь, думая что результат выполнения оператора переноса строки зависит от того в каких он кавычках находится!!!

Comment: @DemoS, во-первых, перенос строки - это не оператор, а escape-последовательность спец символа с кодом 0x0A. 
А во-вторых, [RTFM][1].

    var_dump("\n" == '\n'); // bool(false)

  [1]: http://php.net/types.string

Comment: Ладно, с этим соглашусь, убедил. Только вот как это относится к скорости выполнения вывода строки?

Comment: тут уже приведена ссылка на хабр где ясно сказано что полезнее гуглить на другие темы

Answer (score 1):

Больше всего сервер нагружают функции, написанные кодерами, до сих пор не знающими, что [экономия на спичках и преждевременная оптимизация](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization) - это корень всех зол.

И да, быстрее всего будет работать [инструкция OUT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language).

Comment: Т.е. быдлокольте товарищи, оптимизировать будем строго БД и кеширование, и каГбы если на сайт огромная нагрузка то надо бороться за каждую спичку... <br>
Корень всех зол это программисты которые отказываются принимать простые, <b>удобные</b> правила мотивируя это всем чем угодно кроме как тем что им абсолютно всеравно...<br><small>ИМХО</small>

Comment: Оптимизировать будем строго bottleneck, и если таковым является БД и отсутствие кеширования, то да, оптимизировать будем именно их, а не мифические кавычки и функции-синонимы.

> огромная нагрузка то надо бороться за каждую спичку... 

Ни один highload проект не борется за каждую спичку. Отнюдь, highload борются с оптимизациями на спичках, т.к. такие оптимизации  - это в лучшем случае пустая трата драгоценного времени разработчиков, а в худшем - не читабельный и не поддающийся доработки код.

Большие нагрузки-же выдерживают за счет грамотной масштабируемой архитектуры.

Comment: ну знаете ли - когда Вам надо вызывать одни и теже функции по 100 раз за 10 строк :) - ненароком начинаешь задумываться о том можно ли как то снизить нагрузку и сделать быстрей скрипт.

Comment: ИМХО программист который пишет грамотно должен писать грамотно во всем а не только правильно строить архитектуру.

Comment: @Fatahan, если вы проведете профилирование этого кода и оно покажет, что узким место является именно echo/print, а не, к примеру, плохая архитектура приводящая к слишком частому и не эффективному вызову этих функций, то да, можете смело считать замену echo на print оптимизацией. В остальных случаях - это экономия на спичках.

Comment: > ИМХО программист который пишет грамотно должен писать грамотно во всем а не только правильно выстраивать архитектуру.

Согласен. Код нужно писать грамотный, легко читаемый, хорошо задокументированный, следующий единому стандарту и четко описывающий заранее продуманный алгоритм. И выбор между print/echo тут не более, чем выбор между красным или синим фломастером.

Comment: <b>echo</b>, а не <b>print</b> везде используется и это даже не обсуждается, не?<br>Во всяком случае в моей практике никогда не обсуждалось юзать print или echo :)

Comment: ОффТоп - Попробуйте реку красным фломастером нарисовать :)
По Теме - Между фломастерами есть различия...Я просто уверен что принт и эхо по разному нагружают сервер - один больше - другой меньше - И мне это нужно узнать...А не разводить тут что - Я возможно не правильно пишу код и считаю нагрузку от каждой функции :)

Comment: > А не разводить тут что - Я возможно не правильно пишу код и считаю нагрузку от каждой функции :)

Я не говорил, что вы не правильно пишете код. Я лишь сказал, что перед тем как что-либо оптимизировать, нужно проводить профилирование рабочего кода и убедится, что именно это место необходимо оптимизировать. Вы проводили профилирование хотя бы при помощи [xDebug'а][1]?

  [1]: http://inroot.ru/2010-09/profiling-wit-xdebug.html

Comment: Да нет - я же Нуп :)

Answer (score 0):

Одинарная кавычка не только быстрее работает, но и удобнее с html, далее на примере:

```
echo "<a href=\"link.html\">Link</a>";
echo '<a href="link.html">Link</a>';
```

Comment: не лучший пример, сдесь можно было просто написать не:<br>
echo "<a href=\"link.html\">Link</a>";<br>a<br>
echo "<a href='link.html'>Link</a>"; <br><b>:p</b>

Comment: у каждого свои замуты) для этого и существует универсальность и способности!

Comment: согласен с AlexWindHope - код проще , читабельный и без проблем работает.